# specify type of generic class from user input

Tags: java

I am wondering if this is even possible?

```java
       Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Specify type of Double Linked List:");
       String type = kb.next();
       DoubleLinkedList<type> DLL = new DoubleLinkedList<type>();
```

I am trying to specify the type based on the user input. But, I am getting a compiler error [cannot find symbol .... symbol : class type].

Comment: However you can do this with Arrays http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/arrayInstance.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify generic types in the runtime. They must be known at the compilation time.

This is because Java compiler "hides" using generics during compilation and after compiling the code there is no sign of them.

Comment: I should've known better... Spot on answer!

Comment: If you're interested in details how this replacements works you can visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html